# How do I prevent a HP Pavilion DV6700 from overheating?

Tags: 11.10, power-management

Well this version makes my system so hot that I can use it anymore. A friend i introduced this version to wants me to completely remove Ubuntu.

Specs:
HP Pavilion DV6700
Windows 7/11.10 64bit 
Intel Core 2 Duo 2.0ghz
Intel965GM graphic card
232GB HDD
4GB RAM

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: Please help Jorge Castro i don't want to remove Ubuntu but this heating problem, if not solvable, gives me no option but to remove Ubuntu

Comment: What kind of laptop is it?

Comment: HP PAVILION DV6700 even Windows 7 is cooler and quiter as compared to this version ONLY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, i noticed that my nvidia PC is slower at graphics with unity3d. And a lot faster with unity2d. You may want to try running unity2d for a test.

Meanwhile read this: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/linux-kernel-power-issue-fix.html . Do it and test your results.

Comment: I read that yesterday but I didn't want to mess with my Grub settings

Comment: It's really not a problem. I do it on any machine i have. You can revert grub settings very easily. But you decide.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for this model laptop reveals this [forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1599733) talking about how to manage power on that laptop.

First install the utilities:

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

Then set a conservative governor:

```
sudo cpufreq-set -g conservative
```

According to thinkwiki:

> They differs in the way they scale up and down. The ondemand governor switches to the highest frequency immediately when there is load, while the conservative governor increases frequency step by step. Likewise they behave the other way round for stepping down frequency when the CPU is idle. The conservative governor is good for battery powered environments on AMD64 (but may not work on older ThinkPads like the T21). Ondemand may not work on older laptops without Enhanced SpeedStep due to latency reasons. Anyway, for recent enough Intel CPU, ondemand is the one recommended for power efficiency (over userspace, and even over "powersave") by the Intel's kernel developer Arjan van de Ven

Though that might be a little bit out of date. You might want to try it and see how the laptop runs for a while.

References:

- [How to use cpufrequtils](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_use_cpufrequtils)
- http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_make_use_of_Dynamic_Frequency_Scaling

Comment: Terminal reports 'solid-powermanagement: command not found'

Comment: Oh that's some KDE specific thing, updated my answer

Comment: Ok does this method mean the CPU will work below its optimum ability?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Marginally cooler but still hoter than Windows 7