# Script to tell 12.04 Kernel to maintain battery power saving features on AC

Tags: 12.04, battery, overheating

Laptop runs perfectly cool on battery but immediately I remove the battery the laptop goes all guns blazing and begins to overheat. How can I instruct the Kernel to maintain the power saving features (used on battery) when using AC?

HP PAVILION DV6700
Intel Core 2 Duo 2.0Ghz
4gb RAM
Intel Mobile Chipset 965GM (x3100)

Jupiter is already installed and set to Power savings. Problem is once the kernel detects it running on battery it sort of ignores Jupiter and other power saving features. It seems these fears only kick in when running on battery.

Jupiter does keep power savings on but the laptop starts to overheat ONLY on AC. I just want it to run like how it does when running on battery.

Comment: hey you posted this 2 times?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/69355/how-do-i-prevent-a-hp-pavilion-dv6700-from-overheating does the accepted vote work now?

Comment: It did help but since it was a kernel issue, 12.04 fixed it (at least on battery). This question is quite different from the old one as the issue is fixed on battery. Just need same to be replicated on AC

Comment: You might try enabling laptop-mode (using `laptop-mode-tools`).  You can force it to run even on AC.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh laptop_mode is installed and already enabled

Comment: ...you mean enabled on AC?  You have to force it to do that.

Comment: how do I force it on AC? I just removed the battery and run the 'sudo laptop_mode' command. I saw the laptop mode enabled output. Does this mean I have forced it on AC?

Comment: On AC means you have the power cord plugged in.  You aren't really supposed to remove the battery except to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit /etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf and change

```
ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_AC=0
```

to

```
ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_AC=1
```

Now restart laptop-mode with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/laptop-mode restart
```

Check that it's active on AC with for example:

```
$ sudo laptop_mode start
```

which gives me:

```
Laptop mode 
enabled, 
active [unchanged]
```

Comment: can you also help me out as the temperature of my hard drive surges on AC but runs so cool on battery